# Batch script to read numerical part of file and rename with next higher integer

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a file, such as -

`foofile_1.ext`

A script should read the numerical part of the file, and then rename the file with the next integer, i.e., after execution, the file name should be

`foofile_2.ext`

I can do it with a `C++ / c` application or even in `bash` but not sure how to write a `batch` script to perform this rename. The filename before the `_` isn't going to change, and `_` will aaways appear in the same position within the filename.

I can strip the filename to `_`, but recognizing the numerical is an implementation I am not familiar with. Once I recognize the numerical, I can increment it and rename the file.

Comment: What happens if the next integer exists already? Also as a not new member here, are you expecting us to find an existing question or answer on this site for you and link it? to write the code for you? or something else? The intention of this site is to assist you with an issue resulting from your provided code, not to provide code to your specifications.

Comment: Regretfully I don't have much experience with Batch scripting. I looked at a few answers, but they were about batch renaming, or dealing with other aspects. I can write application level or bash code, but this is more of a simple script, so batch would work better. A nudge or hint in the right direction will be much appreciated, specifically in recognizing the numerical digit.

Comment: A `for` command using the `/f` option could be used to split a string using tokens and delimiters, and a `set` command using the `/a` option can be used to increment a 32-bit signed integer. Please open a Command Prompt window, type `for /?`, press the `[ENTER]` key and read its usage information. You can do similarly using `set /?`. Alternatively use the site search facility, I can guarantee that the task of incrementing an integer as part of a filename, has been asked and answered before. If you need to validate that the substring beyond the underscore is an integer, you can try `findstr /?`

Comment: I can split the string using `_` as a delimiter, and increment an integer, and set file name, yes, but I am having trouble with capturing the integer part, can the numeric substring be simply incremented? in most answers, as I mentioned, they do batch renaming, so it starts with 0 or 1 and renames all files incrementally. Here I need to capture the specific numeric and increment that. I suppose I'll try and blindly increment and see where it goes. Thank you.

Comment: Yes a numeric substring can be numerically incremented using `set /a var += 1` , _(however you may need to be careful that it is not misunderstood as octal)_. If you want us to help you with an issue exhibited by your code, you need to supply that code. You've already told us that you've tried various things, and that you have successfully peformed many of the individual components, so there is absolutely no reason not to [edit] your question to include it. _Otherwise you're simply looking for someone else to do it for you_.

Comment: Tried it out, just incrementing the captured split numeric variable works. I can then use `ren` to rename the file with the incremented variable. I'll add some more code to detect if indeed it is a numeric (between 0 and 9 for each split numeric) to make it safe before incrementing.

Comment: I should additionally point out, _(in addition to the potential octal issue)_, that should the digit count be unknown, not fixed, its value exceeds a maximum limit, or possibly be prepended with one or more zeroes, there could also be issues. Using `set /a` directly will only be safe under certain restrictions, for whatever sequence of digits follow the underscore in your files' basename. As you've not provided any code, or that information, it is not possible for your question to be answered with any certainty of success. _The current answer, does not cater for some of the above either!_

Answer (score 0):

Something to consider is that renaming `foofile_1.ext` to `foofile_2.ext` will fail should `foofile_2.ext` already exist. One way to get around it is to rename in descending numerical order, I posted an answer like that before on SO.

I am however not going to post the same answer here, nor link that answer. I will however show one other method:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "tokens=1,*delims=_" %%i in ('dir /b /a-d "*_*.ext"') do (
     echo %%~nj | findstr /R /V /C:"[A-Z]">nul && (
     set /a numeric=%%~nj+1
     ren "%%~i_%%~j" "%%~i_-hld-!numeric!%%~xj"
   )
)
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b /a-d "*_-hld-*.ext"') do (
    set "name=%%~f"
    ren "%%~f" !name:-hld-=!
)
```

Considering that your input is as you said and does not contain earlier `_`'s anywhere. This will just take each file with the `*_*.ext` format. We split by the `_` into two tokened metavaiables (`%%i` and `%%j`) We take the numeric value and increment by one, then rejoin `%%i` which is pre `_`. This however is where the problem comes when the file you are trying to rename to exists, so for that, first we test if `%%~nj` does not have Alphabetical characters only, using `findstr` (not doing special characters in this free code) Secondly we give a temporary addition to the name to prevent name clashing.

Once we are done, we simply do a rename on all the files containing the `_-hld-` temp inclusion.